# Print elements in array?

Tags: arrays, perl, element

How can i print from 2nd to last element in array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array slice,

```
print @array[1 .. $#array];
```

using foreach loop to insert newlines,

```
print "$_\n" for @array[1 .. $#array];
```

or

```
print "$array[$_]\n" for 1 .. $#array;
```

Comment: A bit more straightforward: `print "$array[$_]\n" for 1 .. $#array;`